# static thread function access non-static class member in C++

Tags: c++

```
Class Test{
    int value;
    static void* thread_func(void* args){
        value++;
    }
    void newthread(){
        pthread_create(&thread_func,...);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a thread in `Class Test.` Therefore compiler forces me to make `thread_func` static. However I cannot access the non-static member "`value`" anymore. It says:

```
invalid use of member 'Class::value' in static member function
```

Is there a way around it?

Comment: I've updated my post. Check it out!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> However I cannot access the non-static
>   member "value" anymore.

That is because `static` function in your class doesn't have (and **cannot** have ) `this` pointer. All you need to pass the pointer to your `Test` object to [pthread_create()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) function as **fourth** argument, and then do this:

```
static void* thread_func(void* args)
{
      Test *test = static_cast<Test*>(args);
      test->value++;
      //write return statement properly
}
```

---

However, if you're doing too many things in `thread_func()` that require access to `Test` class members at many places, then I would suggest this design:

```
//this design simplifies the syntax to access the class members!
class Test
{
    //code omitted for brevity

    static void* thread_func(void* args)
    {
          Test *test = static_cast<Test*>(args);
          test->run(); //call the member function!
          //write return statement properly
    }
    void run() //define a member function to run the thread!
    { 
          value++;//now you can do this, because it is same as 'this->value++;
          //you do have 'this' pointer here, as usual; 
          //so access other members like 'value++'.
    }
    //code omitted for brevity
  }
```

---

## Better design : define a reusable class!

Even better would be to define a **reusable** class with *pure* virtual function `run()` to be implemented by the derived classes. Here is how it should be designed:

```
//runnable is reusable class. All thread classes must derive from it! 
class runnable
{
public:
    virtual ~runnable() {}
    static void run_thread(void *args)
    {
        runnable *prunnable = static_cast<runnable*>(args);
        prunnable->run();
    }
protected:
    virtual void run() = 0; //derived class must implement this!
};

class Test : public runnable //derived from runnable!
{
public:
    void newthread()
    {
        //note &runnable::run_thread
        pthread_create(&runnable::run_thread,..., this);
    }
protected:
    void run() //implementing the virtual function!
    {
        value++; // your thread function!
    }
}
```

Looks better?

Answer (score 1):

Let thread_func take a pointer to an object of the class as argument.

```
static void* thread_func(void* pThis)
{
    static_cast<Test*>(pThis)->value++;
}
```

In case, this method wants to take some other information as well, put both in another `struct/class` and pass that in.

Comment: Pointer to an object. Classes don't exist at runtime in C++ so you can't have a pointer to a class.